# how to send the data to server and update repeatedly in a certain time interval in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

this is my code of current location. i'm new to android so can anyone help me out ?

i need to send the current location to server and update it i certain time interval so that the user can fetch the location and display it on the map.it is basically a tracking device.

```
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Service where you can pull or push data to server repeatedly.

Comment: i read about alarmmanager class 'm not getting how to use it

Comment: The better way is to use SyncAdapter which will send data to server and receive. Android will handle all the scenarios.

Comment: Can you suggest me any reference.  Any website that can help me out

Comment: See, that is also based on your requirement if you want send your data periodically you could use alarm manager for regular wake up. But if you want to send your data immediately but in a queue or sequence then You should use intent service.

Comment: I wanted to send the data periodically but I am not getting how to use the alarm manager with the above code